# crear carpetas parametrizadas con fechas

Tags: java, sql

Hola a la toda la comunidad, resulta que tengo que alojar información y guardarla en carpetas que se creen según su fecha de consulta tipo año>mes>día>archivo.txt y así por cada archivo que encuentre según la información consultada actualmente tengo una consulta que me trae la fecha actual

`

```
    Calendar sessiondate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");                
    SimpleDateFormat syear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat smonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
    SimpleDateFormat sday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    
    String fecha = sdf.format(sessiondate.getTime());
    String Year = syear.format(sessiondate.getTime());        
    String Month = smonth.format(sessiondate.getTime());        
    String Day = sday.format(sessiondate.getTime());`
```

mi pregunta es si traigo datos entre dos fechas por ejemplo

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2021-04-21 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

como hago para obtener el año, mes y dia de esa consulta directamente y alojarlo por las carpetas de esas fechas ?

Comment: Entiendo tu problema, más sin embargo me gustaría que compartieras que haz hecho, adicional a esa petición, mi sugerencia es que si bien traes información y si es de una BD mucho mejor ya que solo tienes que regresar la fecha y listo concatenarla en el nombre del archivo,

Comment: ¿cuál es el nombre del campo que tiene la información de fecha?